# Is it possible to iterate through a JSON to find if a property exists?

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to do an experiment with google API geolocation.

and I noticed the JSON is not always the same: sometimes the address is a child of a property, sometimes it is not.

For example, if I want to extract for instance the value of PostalCode, it's sometimes:

```
...SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber
```

And sometimes is:

```
...AdministrativeArea.DependentLocality.Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber
```

There is no way to know the exact path ot the value. How can I find the value of **PostalCodeNumber** independently of its parents?

Comment: I'd say the most expeditious way would be to use a regex to get the whole path that includes PostalCodeNumber, then pass that to eval.  Purists might hate that, but it should work, and I don't think it'll cause the world to end

Comment: Are you using the v2 API? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3491048/171703

Comment: sounds good...If I knew how to do it...

Comment: yes still v2... and for the moment i cannot change to v3

Comment: @Francesco, why can't you change to v3? Don't forget that they've said v2 is going to go away after three years!

Comment: shoot, now that i solved it...i tried quickly v3 but i have way more problme identifying each component fo the address...I'll have time nex months to find an alternative then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the inJSON plugin here: http://danconnor.com/search-for-a-key-in-json-with-jquery-$.injson.html

NOTE: I thought I saw jQuery tagged here. Did you remove it or am I seeing things? Anyway, it would be easy to convert this to non-jQuery. It's a simple recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

put this on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnzTD/1/) for you to try

```
function GetPropIn( obj, prop )
{
    for( sProperty in obj )
    {
        if( obj.hasOwnProperty( sProperty ) )
        {
            if( sProperty == prop )
            {
                return( obj[sProperty] );
            }
            else
            {
                if( typeof(obj[sProperty]) == "object" )
                {
                    var res = GetPropIn( obj[sProperty], prop );
                    if( res )
                    {
                        return( res );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```